# Aggregate functions return wrong values when joining more tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, aggregate-functions

I want to display all customers and their addresses and the number and total sum of their orders. My query looks like this:

```
select *, sum(o.tota), count(o.total) 
from customer c 
natural join orders o
group by c.custId;
```

which works fine.

but if I add a new table to the query:

```
select *, sum(o.tota), count(o.total) 
from customer c 
natural join orders o
natural join cust_addresses a
group by c.custId;
```

then it won't work anymore. the aggregate functions return wrong values because there may be multiple addresses per customer, which is correct, I also want to display all their addresses.
What can I do to solve the aggregate function problem?

I could think of doing something like:

```
select *, (select total from orders o where o.custid=c.custid), ..
from customer c 
natural join orders o
natural join cust_addresses a
group by c.custId;
```

But this is very slow.

***EDIT***
I now tried the following but it tells me that field c.custid is unknown:

```
select *
from
     customer c,               
     left join (select sum(o.tota), count(o.total) from orders o where o.custid=c.custid) as o
where ...
group by c.custId;
```

Comment: How do you want to handle customers that have no orders? Your current query omits them.

Comment: year right, I forgot the left for the left join :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution: Use two queries.

Otherwise you can do your aggregated calculation in a subquery (on the whole table, not per row) then JOIN the result of the subquery with the addresses table to get your extra data. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer T1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT custId,
           SUM(total) AS sum_total,
           COUNT(total) AS count_total
    FROM orders
    -- WHERE ...
    GROUP BY custId
) T2
ON T1.custId = T2.custId
-- WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it now but it didn't work for me. it seems I cannot access the outer tables from within the subselect. See my edits please.

Comment: @codymanix: You can't access an alias from an inner query in an outer query.

Comment: No I want to access an alias from the outer query in the inner query. I want to use the customer c which is defined in the outer query in the where clause of the inner query.

Comment: @codymanix: Why do you want to do that? If custId is a PK for the customer table, doesn't it just give the same result in the end?

Comment: @codymanix: Your question is not clear. Perhaps you could state your full requirements and explain why this answer doesn't meet those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select c.custId, max(c.custName) custName, ...
       a.addrId, max(a.addrLine1) addrLine1, ...
       sum(o.total) order_total, count(o.total) order_count
from customer c 
left join orders o on c.custId = o.custId
left join cust_addresses a on c.custId = a.custId
group by c.custId, a.addrId;
```

assuming you want all customers, whether or not they have any orders or addresses.

Comment: But then the sum and count is not displayed correctly if the customer has more than one order or address.

Comment: @codymanix, did you include the cust_address key field (which I have called addrId, since you haven't posted the table structure) in the group by clause of your query? If so, the sum and count should be returned correctly.

Comment: but then I have multiple rows for one customer returned.

Comment: @codymanix: yes, where there is more than one address per customer, you will get one line per address per customer. You **explicitly** said in your question that you wanted to display "all their addresses"; this query resolves the aggregate function problem **and** displays all their addresses.