# Simpler way to do a SUM with a fanout on a join

Tags: sql

**Note:** SQL backend does not matter, any mainstream relational DB is fine (postgres, mysql, oracle, sqlserver)

There is an interesting [article on Looker](https://help.looker.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023722974) that tells about the technique they use to provide correct totals when a JOIN results in a fanout, along the lines of:

```
# In other words, using a hash to remove any potential duplicates (assuming a Primary Key).
SUM(DISTINCT big_unique_number + total) - SUM(DISTINCT big_unique_number)
```

A good way to simulate the fanout it just doing something like this:

```
WITH Orders AS (
    SELECT 10293 AS id, 2.5 AS rate UNION ALL 
    SELECT 210293 AS id, 3.5
),
     Other AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
)
SELECT SUM(rate) FROM Orders CROSS JOIN Other
-- Returns 12.0 instead of 6.0
```

Their example does something like this, which I think is just a long-form way of grabbing `md5(PK)` with all the fancy footwork to get around the 8-byte limitation (so they do a `LEFT(...)` then a `RIGHT(...)`:

```
 (COALESCE(CAST( ( SUM(DISTINCT (CAST(FLOOR(COALESCE(users.age ,0)
 *(1000000*1.0)) AS DECIMAL(38,0))) + 
 CAST(STRTOL(LEFT(MD5(CONVERT(VARCHAR,users.id )),15),16) AS DECIMAL(38,0))
 * 1.0e8 + CAST(STRTOL(RIGHT(MD5(CONVERT(VARCHAR,users.id )),15),16) AS DECIMAL(38,0)) ) 
 - SUM(DISTINCT CAST(STRTOL(LEFT(MD5(CONVERT(VARCHAR,users.id )),15),16) AS DECIMAL(38,0))
 * 1.0e8 + CAST(STRTOL(RIGHT(MD5(CONVERT(VARCHAR,users.id )),15),16) AS DECIMAL(38,0))) ) 
 AS DOUBLE PRECISION) 
 / CAST((1000000*1.0) AS DOUBLE PRECISION), 0)
```

Is there another general-purpose way to do this? Perhaps using a correlated subquery or something else? Or is the above way the best known way to do this?

Two related answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14140884/651174
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333574/651174

---

Without worrying about a general-purpose hashing function (for example, that may take strings), the following works:

```
WITH Orders AS (
    SELECT 10293 AS id, 2.5 AS rate UNION ALL 
    SELECT 210293 AS id, 3.5
),
Other AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
)
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT id + rate) - SUM(DISTINCT id) FROM Orders CROSS JOIN Other
-- 6.0
```

But this still begs the question: is there another / better way to do this in a very general-purpose manner?

Comment: Some sample data would benefit your question, as it would not force the reader to read the external article to understand.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just updated it with a working query, do you want to let me know if that works?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the `sum(rate)` directly in the first subquery `WITH Orders AS(...)` ?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using (your query wouldn't work in Postgres or Oracle to begin with). If you want a DBMS independent answer, then the `sql` tag is enough.

Comment: @Edouard there's no subquery, that's a CTE to simulate a table to make the query/data reproducible.

Comment: @David542 - Yes I agree with you, that's a CTE rather than a subquery ... but my question is still valid : Why don't you calculate the `sum(rate)` directly in the CTE `WITH Orders AS (...)` ? This would make the query much simpler, readable and efficient, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Edouard oh, I see. Yea, I don't have access to the underlying table. I'm just using that cte-table as temporary data so someone can test the question easily without having to create tables on their own.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name why wouldn't it work with Postgres? I tested on 13.1 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Because there is no `strol` or `convert()` function in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh you mean for the general-case then, correct? Not the last query I wrote in the question. Out of curiosity, how would you approach this problem in a generic way (such as if writing an ORM or query-generation library) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical example for the joins mutilating the aggregation is this:

```
select
  posts.id,
  count(likes.id) as likes_total,
  count(dislikes.id) as dislikes_total
from posts
left join likes on likes.post_id = posts.post_id
left join dislikes on dislikes.post_id = posts.post_id
group by posts.id;
```

where both counts result in the same number, because each gets multiplied by the other. With 2 likes and 3 dislikes, both counts are 6.

The simple solution is: Aggregate before joining. If you want to know the likes and dislikes counts per post, join the likes and dislikes counts to the posts.

```
select posts.id, l.likes_total, d.dislikes_total
from posts
left join
(
  select post_id, count(*) as likes_total
  from likes
  group by post_id
) l on l.post_id = posts.post_id
left join
(
  select post_id, count(*) as dislikes_total
  from dislikes
  group by post_id
) d on d.post_id = posts.post_id
group by posts.id;
```

Use `COALESCE`, if you want to see zeros instead of nulls.

Don't try to muddle through with tricks. Just aggregate, then join. You can of course replace the joins with lateral joins (which are correlated subqueries), if the DBMS supports them. Or for single aggregates as in the example even move the correlated subqueries to the select clause. That's mainly personal preference, but depending on the DBMS's optimizer one solution may be faster than the other. (Ideally the optimizer would come up with the same execution plan for all those queries of course.)

Comment: @thorstern -- thanks for this answer. Out of curiosity, why do you think Looker uses the complex trick then instead of using an approach similar to the above, which seems much more maintainable to me?

Comment: Looker seems to be a tool that tries to help you retrieve BI data. They have noticed that many users are inexperienced with query writing when it comes to multiple aggregates and hence tend to fall into the multiplication trap. So, the developers made Looker alter the user's SQL behind the scenes such that a properly written query still works, while an improper aggregation query may get rescued and still show the desired results in spite of being written incorrectly. Thus they get their clients satisfied with the tool. If the clients wrote proper queries the trick would not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use a larger datatype to shift the values out of the way. This is similar to the first example without the potential for collisions. It probably also has minor performance benefits in not having to execute two different distinct sums.

```
 sum(distinct id * 1000000000 + value) % 1000000000
```

The principle is to package up the values into a single unit. For the most flexibility you'd want to convert to something like a wide decimal type in order to accommodate the full range. With strings it's easY to generate a new surrogate id via `dense_rank()` That would also let you collapse the key width according to the number of expect key values.

Ultimately though, I think the ultimate answer is no. There's not a one size fits all approach, especially across the spectrum of the various aggregate functions going beyond variations in mixed data types.

Comment: sure, that works, but I mean for a general-purpose PK, for example, if the id is a string. Also on a large number couldn't this overflow?

Comment: Of course. But it's already an improvement on their answer which allows for collisions in the sums.

Answer (score 0):

--Approaching the solution such that fanout phenomenon a natural consequence of cross join.

```
    ;WITH Orders AS (
        SELECT 10293 AS id, 2.5 AS rate UNION ALL 
        SELECT 210293 AS id, 3.5
    ),  Other AS (
        SELECT 1 as oth_id UNION ALL SELECT 2 as oth_id
    )
    ,   FanDepth AS (
        SELECT count(*) as depth from Other
    )
    SELECT  SUM(rate) / depth 
    FROM 
    Orders CROSS JOIN Other CROSS JOIN FanDepth 
    Group by depth
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best option is always to `SUM` data before to join via a subquery or a cte

```
WITH 
Orders AS (
    SELECT 10293 AS id, 2.5 AS rate 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 210293 AS id, 3.5
),
Other AS (
    SELECT 1 other
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2
)
select *
from (
    SELECT SUM(rate) rate
    FROM Orders 
) OrdersSummed 
CROSS JOIN Other
```

or

```
WITH 
Orders AS (
    SELECT 10293 AS id, 2.5 AS rate 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 210293 AS id, 3.5
),
Other AS (
    SELECT 1 other
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2
),
OrdersSummed AS (
    SELECT SUM(rate) rate
    FROM Orders 
) s
select *
from OrdersSummed 
CROSS JOIN Other
```